# Verifying the $N_k$ in Waring's Theorem (Probability)

Tags: probability-theory

I know that there are proofs on Waring's Theorem on StackExchange, but I plan on tackling it without looking at the proof. The [statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qpde.jpg) follows from Grimmet and Stirzaker's *Probability and Random Processes*. This might be pretty silly, but I've actually had a pretty hard time trying to understand what is meant by $N_k$. Assuming that $n=3$ and $k=2$, would it mean that $N_k = \{A_1 \cap A_2, A_1 \cap A_3, A_2 \cap A_3 \}$? And that we're looking for $\mathbb{P}(N_k) = (A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_1 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3)$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in your example

$$N_2=\color{red}{\big((A_1\cap A_2)\setminus A_3\big)}\cup\color{blue}{\big(A_1\cap A_3)\setminus A_2\big)}\cup\big((A_2\cap A_3)\setminus A_1\big)\;.$$

The event that $A_1$ and $A_2$ occur but $A_3$ does not is red; the event that $A_1$ and $A_3$ occur but $A_2$ does not is blue; and the event that $A_2$ and $A_3$ occur but $A_1$ does not is black.

In order for **exactly** $2$ of the $3$ events to occur, not only must some pair, like $A_1$ and $A_3$, occur, but the remaining one must **fail** to occur. Your

$$(A_1\cap A_2)\cup(A_1\cap A_3)\cup(A_2\cap A_3)$$

includes the event that all three occur, and indeed includes it three times, once in each of the parenthesized terms.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gnesmik: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

An event is a subset of the sample space, not a set of subsets.  Also, for $n=3$ and $k=2$, the event
$$(A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_1 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3)$$
is in english "At least two of the $A_i$ occur".

Instead, we'd have $$N_k = (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3^c) \cup (A_1 \cap A_2^c \cap A_3) \cup (A_1^c \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$$ where $A_i^c$ denotes the complementary event.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the event not being a set of subsets!